# Keyframe of object property is saved but not applied to model (MB-Lab)

Tags: keyframes, makehuman

I have a human model from MB-Lab and I need to change the character mass over time. I can change the mass and save the value for a frame `i` and when scrubbing through the timeline I can see the value changing inside of this MB-Lab configuration box. However, the values aren't applied to the model itself, such that it stays at a single `character_mass` value. Am I changing the wrong variable or using the wrong `data_path` in `keyframe_insert()`? I was already able to keyframe a bone which is working flawlessly and how I expected it to be for `character_mass` as well.

```py
random_mass = random.uniform(-0.9, 0.9)
bpy.data.objects["m_ca01"].character_mass = random_mass
bpy.data.objects["m_ca01"].keyframe_insert(data_path="character_mass", frame=i)
print(bpy.data.objects["m_ca01"].character_mass)
```

Blender 3.0.1 on Ubuntu; MB-Lab 1.7.8

Comment: MB-Lab uses a two part process.  Prior to finalizing the model, you can change parameters like `character_mass` and the model will change to match; but once you finalize the model those parameters are ignored.

Comment: @MartyFouts Actually I haven't used the "finalize" function yet. For my project I'm currently using a human model from MB-Lab, randomly change a few parameters, render an image and repeat. This works fine in a loop, but I want to use keyframes for an animation, so that I can export this animation to multiple nodes for speeding up the rendering. However, now that I'm thinking about this a bit more, I could simply run the loop on different devices. The parameters are random whatsoever and there's no certain order - I could simply dump all outputs into a single pool.